# How to use Aquamacs for SBCL development?

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, aquamacs

I'm new to Lisp. Working on a Mac, SBCL was installed with brew. I have done Lisp exercises in the terminal, writing files with BBEdit and running from terminal. Time to take advantage of a better Lisp environment, so I installed Aquamacs. I have Aquamacs running, quicklisp is installed, and SLIME is installed.

However, when I enter Lisp code in Aquamacs it goes in just like in any editor. I understand Emacs and by extension Aquamacs can do completion of identifiers, do parenthesis management and automatic indentation, but Aquamacs isn't doing those things. How do I do get automatic parenthesis, identifier completion, and automatic indenting working?

Comment: Thanks to Rainer for adding the tag. But would that Rainer had dropped a pearl!

Comment: Yes Aquamacs fits in with macOS well but unfortunately it is still on emacs 25.3 and so many newer packages don't work. You might want to look at plain GNU emacs or the mituharu(aka railwaycat on Homebrew)  ports

Answer (score 4):

This may be a good place to start

https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/.

Its a while since I looked at Aquamacs. I moved from it to macport emacs (aka railwaycat) , also installable via homebrew mainly because I found some things did not work so well ( please don't ask what as I just dont remember, it was quite a while ago!) and the scrolling and rendering was far superior.

YOu will defintely want to look at installing quicklisp and Slime or Sly. There are numerous tutorials available. Here is one that is very helpful

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiks_HJ3Kn5AhV34TgGHQpmBN4QwqsBegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DVnWVu8VVDbI&usg=AOvVaw09yA6kxHU34QX7tLtJv1j-

Hope that helps